# After accepting your own answer it appears twice in reputation history

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow

Seems like a small bug, or if it's by design I'm afraid I miss something. When I answer my own question (happens) and then accept it (happens as well) then I see it appearing twice in my reputation history. Whereas when I accept someone else's answer, it just appears once, as expected.

As an example, see [my history on SO of March 10, 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/111575?Tab=Reputation&StartDate=2011-03-10&EndDate=2011-03-10), a day I cleaned up three questions and they oddly appeared twice in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design.  (:

Remember that when you're not self-accepting, 2 rep gains are handed out:

- +2 to you for accepting an answer
- +15 to the answerer

So, that's what each instance in your rep history represents.  It is just a little funky since you don't get any rep for the self-accept.

Comment: Ah, I was trying to think of some logic twist behind this behavior, this makes perfect sense (however odd it may look in the history, esp. considering both have zero rep).